# Styling PHP echo table

Tags: php, css, sql, twitter-bootstrap

I have finally figured out how to make my SQL table display using PHP however I am having a hell of a time getting the styles to show up. Here's what I have so far, any pointers on how to style the echo? Nothing shows up. Is how I am doing this the improper way to style an echo? I am trying to style it with Bootstrap CSS.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Abacus PHP SQL Server Connection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $db_host = '***';
            $db_user = '***';   //recommend using a lower privileged user
            $db_pwd = '***';
            $database = '***';
            $table = '***';

            $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $db_user, "PWD" => $db_pwd, "Database"=>$database); 
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $db_host, $connectionInfo);
            if( !$conn )
            {
                 echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
                 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }

            $tsql = "SELECT category, data_desc, data_source, update_cycle,ISNULL(datename(mm,last_abadata_update) + + ' ' + DATENAME(dd,last_abadata_update) + ', ' + DATENAME(yyyy, last_abadata_update),'') AS last_abadata_update, ISNULL(datename(mm,last_abadata2_update) + ' ' + DATENAME(dd,last_abadata2_update) + ', ' + DATENAME(yyyy,last_abadata2_update),'') AS last_abadata2_update FROM {$table} ORDER BY category, data_source, data_desc";
            $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
            if (!$result) {
             die("Query to show fields from table failed");
            }

            echo "<table >";
            echo "<tr>";

            // printing table headers with desired column names
            echo "<td style='border=1px solid black;Font-size=18;Font-Weight=bold'>";
            echo "Category";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td style='border=1px solid black;Font-size=18;Font-Weight=bold'>";
            echo "Description";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td style='border=1px solid black;Font-size=18;Font-Weight=bold'>";
            echo "Source";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td style='border=1px solid black;Font-size=18;Font-Weight=bold'>";
            echo "Update Cycle";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td style='border=1px solid black;Font-size=18;Font-Weight=bold'>";
            echo "Last AbaData Update";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td style='border=1px solid black;Font-size=18;Font-Weight=bold'>";
            echo "Last AbaData 2.0 Update";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td style='border=1px solid black'>";
                echo $row['category']; 
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td style='border=1px solid black'>";
                echo $row['data_desc']; 
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td style='border=1px solid black'>";
                echo $row['data_source']; 
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td style='border=1px solid black'>";
                echo $row['update_cycle'];  
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td style='border=1px solid black'>";
                echo $row['last_abadata_update'];  
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td style='border=1px solid black'>";
                echo $row['last_abadata2_update'];  
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>\n";
            }
            echo "</table>";

            sqlsrv_free_stmt( $result);
            sqlsrv_close( $conn);
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ... why on earth are you inline styling this anyway?

Comment: I was trying to get anything to show up. I am using Bootstrap classes now. Apparently in my panic had completely forgot how CSS works...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS accepts `:` not `=` so change`style='border=1px solid black'` to `style='border:1px solid black'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS should not be used with Camel Case, try using lowercase styles.

Also you should be using colons not equals for the styles.

```
"<td style='border:1px solid black; font-size:18; font-weight:bold'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like when you styling like this html. Use CSS to style. Add id or class to elements. I even don't echo html elements but instead opening and closing php tags and writing elements in plane html and only when i need to present php var I use php. Someone will say maybe its not good but this is how I do.
Here is how i would do your code:

```
<html><head><title>Abacus PHP SQL Server Connection</title></head><body>
<?php
$db_host = '***';
$db_user = '***';   //recommend using a lower privileged user
$db_pwd = '***';
$database = '***';
$table = '***';

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $db_user, "PWD" => $db_pwd, "Database"=>$database); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $db_host, $connectionInfo);
if( !$conn )
{
     echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$tsql = "SELECT category, data_desc, data_source, update_cycle,ISNULL(datename(mm,last_abadata_update) + + ' ' + DATENAME(dd,last_abadata_update) + ', ' + DATENAME(yyyy, last_abadata_update),'') AS last_abadata_update, ISNULL(datename(mm,last_abadata2_update) + ' ' + DATENAME(dd,last_abadata2_update) + ', ' + DATENAME(yyyy,last_abadata2_update),'') AS last_abadata2_update FROM {$table} ORDER BY category, data_source, data_desc";
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
if (!$result) {
 die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}
?>
<table>
<tr>

<td style="border:1px solid black;Font-size:18;Font-Weight:bold">
Category
</td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;Font-size:18;Font-Weight:bold">
Description
</td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;Font-size:18;Font-Weight:bold">
Source
</td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;Font-size:18;Font-Weight:bold">
Update Cycle
</td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;Font-size:18;Font-Weight:bold">
Last AbaData Update
</td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;Font-size:18;Font-Weight:bold">
Last AbaData 2.0 Update
</td>
</tr>
<?php
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
    <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">
<?php
    echo $row['category']; 
?>
    </td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">
<?php
    echo $row['data_desc']; 
?>
    </td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">
<?php
    echo $row['data_source']; 
?>
    </td>    
    <td style="border:1px solid black">
<?php
    echo $row['update_cycle'];  
?>
    </td>
    <td tyle="border:1px solid black">
<?php
    echo $row['last_abadata_update'];  
?>
    </td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">
<?php
    echo $row['last_abadata2_update'];  
?>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $result);
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
?>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use css like this

```
<style>
    .outside-while{
        border:1px solid black;font-size:18;font-weight:bold;
    }

    .inside-while{
        border:1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

And for all td outside the while loop give class as `outside-while`

Nd for td inside the loop, give class as `inside-while`

example

```
echo "<td class='outside-while'>";
echo "Category";
echo "</td>";
```

And i feel outside it should be `<th>` not `<td>`

Now inside while

```
echo "<td class='inside-while'>";
echo $row['category']; 
echo "</td>";
```